# Spring Boot Admin Compatibility Spring Boot Version and Logging Instances

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I would like to know if there is a **table of compatibility** from Spring Boot Version and Spring Boot Admin.
At the link:
https://start.spring.io/actuator/info
it describes that the compatibility from this 2 components are:

```
"codecentric-spring-boot-admin": {
            "2.2.4": "Spring Boot >=2.2.0.RELEASE and <2.3.0.M1",
            "2.3.1": "Spring Boot >=2.3.0.M1 and <2.5.0-M1"
        }
```

But if I check in the maven repository the Spring Boot Admin Server pom, the version of Spring Boot Admin Server 2.4.3 depends on 2.4.6 of Spring Boot. The link is:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/codecentric/spring-boot-admin-server/2.4.3/spring-boot-admin-server-2.4.3.pom

What is the truth?

Moreover if I use Spring Boot 2.4.8 the spring boot admin 2.4.3 works fine.
There is a rule in order to choiche the best compatibility from Spring Boot and Spring Boot Admin?

**Another question is**: in the 2.1.6 version of Spring Boot Admin, if a service had a lot of instances, in the "Logging -> Logfile" section of Spring Boot Admin is present only 1 type of log for only 1 instance also if I change instance; Is there a bug fixed in the last versions?

Regards.

machsharker6